# Centering text in a button without underlining the hover state. Why is this so hard?

Tags: html, css, button, hover

I want the text centered and not decorated. As you can see, I have a lot of `text decoration:none` CSS not still no dice...I'm so confused. Should the div be inside or outside the link?

HTML -

```
 <a href=""
       data-toggle="modal"
       data-target="#videoModal"
       data-theVideo="http://www.youtube.com/embed/loFtozxZG0s">
      <div class="round-button">
           <i class="fa fa-play"></i>  Watch Trailer
      </div>
    </a>
```

CSS -

```
.round-button {
  width:20%;
  width: 15em;
  height: 3em;
  margin-top: 1em;
  moz-border-radius: 15px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
  background: #f49131;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align:center;
  color:white;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  text-decoration:none;
  cursor:pointer;

}

.round-button:hover {
  background:#f46800;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.round-button a {
  display:block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-decoration:none;
}

.round-button a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Regular State -
[image]

Cursor State - [image]

Comment: It must be pulling in the hover class from somewhere else in your document - have a look at the developer console in your browser and you should be able to target/override the appropriate class from there

Comment: @darrelbarrel try text-decoration:none!important; to see if this is an override issue.

Comment: yes, there is also an override issue as well

Comment: @darrellbarrell Avoid important. See if you can select it properly or you will be this guy http://i.imgur.com/q4g0SYM.jpg in no time!

Comment: important is fine for testing if you have your selector right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your selector is incorrect.

`.round-button a` assumes that the link is a descendant of the `.round-button` class but, in fact the reverse is true.

```css
a .round-button {
  width: 20%;
  width: 15em;
  height: 3em;
  line-height: 3em;
  margin-top: 1em;
  moz-border-radius: 15px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
  background: #f49131;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#videoModal" data-theVideo="http://www.youtube.com/embed/loFtozxZG0s">
  <div class="round-button">
    <i class="fa fa-play"></i> Watch Trailer
  </div>
</a>
```

**In fact you can simplify the whole thing by not using a div and just styling the link**

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/1tvr0ke4/)

Comment: oh geez, true. on a meta level, why should the link be outside the div or vice-versa?

Comment: @darrellbarrell You want the whole div to become a link, so you put it **inside** the `a` tags. Everything inside the tags becomes link. You can link you whole body if you want :)

Comment: I should also point out that [**Links are not buttons**](http://www.karlgroves.com/2013/05/14/links-are-not-buttons-neither-are-divs-and-spans/)